# Boto3 - Get when a Lambda function was last ran or executed

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to know when a Lambda function was last ran (in past 6 days, for example). I wrote the below boto3 code but it is not giving me any data points.

Here's the code:

```
metric = cw_client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace = 'AWS/Lambda',
    MetricName = 'Invocations',
    Dimensions = [
        {
            'Name': 'FunctionaName',
            'Value': 'B2B-Masters-Aggregate'
        }
    ],
    StartTime = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=6),
    EndTime = datetime.utcnow(),
    Period = 300,
    Statistics = ['SampleCount'],
    Unit = 'Count'
)
```

And the output is:

```
{'Label': 'Invocations', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '2209b9fd-b11a-4f54-aeef9f4853fb', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '2209b9fd-b11a-4f54-aeef9f4853fb', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '334', 'date': 'Fri, 27 Oct 2023 15:39:54 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

From the console, I can see that it executed recently like half an hour ago.

I tried `get_metric_data()` as well and it was the same.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in your Dimensions? Should it say FunctionName instead?

```
Dimensions = [
        {
            'Name': '**FunctionaName**',
            'Value': 'B2B-Masters-Aggregate'
        }
    ],
```

You also may want to check that you are executing the code in the same region as your Lambda. If the code is executing on a different region, you will get no results.